# Google sheet importxml and xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I try to import data to google sheet from this website 
https://webb-site.com/ccass/choldings.asp?sort=holddn&sc=2001

I want to import the figure like '29.03' from the line 'Total in CCASS' or from other line too.

I try to use the xpath query from Chrome with no success, it return something like /html/body/div[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]/a"

Then I try =importxpxml(//webb-site.com/ccass/choldings.asp?sort=holddn&sc=2001,"//*[@href='ctothist.asp?issue=24349']")

or =importxpxml(//webb-site.com/ccass/choldings.asp?sort=holddn&sc=2001,"//a/@href='ctothist.asp?issue=24349'/text()")

I am not familiar with xml, so it is really hard. I have already tried other website by try and error with success but this one seems very difficult. Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel,

I was able to fetch both values using:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://webb-site.com/ccass/choldings.asp?sort=holddn&sc=2001","//tr[td/text()='Total in CCASS']/td/a/text()")
```

[image]

Use any values you need.

Note that [here is](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) detailed description of the function including [XPath features](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).

Comment: CroWell, thanks for your prompt. Really help a lot. However, I try to paste to my Google sheet but it still show error. Do I do something wrong?

Comment: Gabriel, looks like remote page has been changed. After quick test using XPath ```//a/text()``` Google fetches only 15 elements and all of them are only from page's header and footer. Sounds like remote page isn't available for Google HTTP agent (e.g. it doesn't show data for agent based on user-agent data) or there are any other internal exceptions caused by remote page changes. Just can say that mentioned above XPath worked but now Google agent can't fetch any data from table you need. May be you should contact site owners for clarifications or use another tool for fetching.

Comment: CroWell, Is that because the website is load by java?

Comment: Who knows, Gabriel, looks like I could only guess here.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your attempts are deficient because of xml or xpath. Instead of:

```
=importxpxml(//webb-site.com/ccass/choldings.asp?sort=holddn&sc=2001, ...
```

try

```
=importxml("https://webb-site.com/ccass/choldings.asp?sort=holddn&sc=2001", ...
```

and similarly for the other. (I will admit *at the moment* the results for both the "corrected" versions and @CroWell's version are for me `#N/A` and *Error Imported content is empty*, though I can access the web site to view. ... But is now back.)

Comment: Sorry for my typo. I did use =importxml not =importxpxml, by using @CroWell's version still got #N/A to me.